# How to use Vue in an existing typescript application without modules?

Tags: vue.js, node-modules

I'm trying to use Vue in "progressive enhancement" mode in an existing site, which already uses Typescript extensively.

[The vue tutorial](https://vuejs.org/tutorial/#step-2) shows code like this:

```
<script type="module">
import { createApp, reactive, ref } from 'vue'

createApp({
  setup() {
    const counter = reactive({ count: 0 })
    const message = ref('Hello World!')

    return {
      counter,
      message
    }
  }
}).mount('#app')
</script>

<div id="app">
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  <p>Count is: {{ counter.count }}</p>
</div>
```

But I don't want to have javascript in the html file, I want to relocate that code to a proper typescript file. But when I do this, I get compilation errors no matter how I try to arrange this.

---

If I don't qualify anything, I get errors like `Error   TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'createApp'.` This makes sense because the whole point of Typescript is to type check and not let you reference unknown things.

---

So I try to import Vue like this:

```
import { Vue } from '../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.global.js';
```

and change the call to `Vue.createApp(...)`. This causes the browser error `Cannot use import statement outside a module`

---

If I try instead:

```
let { Vue } = require('../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.global.js')
```

I get `require is not defined`.

---

I tried getting the vue.d.ts typings from https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/types/vue.d.ts and referencing the file with `/// <reference path="../../Scripts/vue.d.ts" />" />`, but this just doesn't work, giving `Error   TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'Vue'.`

---

I have tried many, many permutations of this but all of them run into one error or another.

So the question is: how can I retrofit Vue into an existing Typescript app without modules?

Comment: why dont you consider using vue cli?

Comment: I tried that and ran into most of the same issues. There are many ways to do this, it seems, but they all generally create a subfolder with its own site, and this causes conflicts with the way the existing site works. But I could easily be missing something here.

Comment: It may sounds like a silly question but have you installed the vue module via npm?

Comment: did you tried thsi? `<script type="module" src="main.js"></script>`

Comment: I tried this but it causes `The requested module '../../node_modules/vue/dist/vue.global.js' does not provide an export named 'Vue'`. That file does look like it exports Vue, but apparently not.